# I am unable to run `apt update` or `apt upgrade` on Maru, why?

Tags: maru-os

I am using Maru v0.6.8 for Nexus 5 (hammerhead).

When I try to run `apt update` or `apt upgrade`, I am unable to establish a connection to the servers, so I cannot perform the update.

What am I doing wrong? Is it still possible to perform an update on Maru?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

The servers for stretch, for your maru-os version, are now accessible at:

`http://archive.debian.org/`

Edit the file:

`nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Add the following lines and comment out or delete the old lines.

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
```

After that, you can run `apt update && apt upgrade`.